# csharp_ls not working with Neovim built-in lsp

Tags: linux, neovim, language-server-protocol, nvim-lspconfig

I installed csharp_ls like in [official nvim lsp docs](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/CONFIG.md#csharp_ls).
I have dotnet-sdk installed:

```
$ dotnet --version
5.0.205
```

as well as csharp-ls:

```
$ whereis csharp-ls
csharp-ls: /home/user/.dotnet/tools/csharp-ls
```

But when I try to run it in neovim, I get this error:

```
:lua require'lspconfig'.csharp_ls.setup{}

E5108: Error executing lua [string ":lua"]:1: attempt to index field 'csharp_ls' (a nil value)
```

My nvim config:

```
call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/plugged')

Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'

Plug 'itchyny/lightline.vim'

Plug 'gruvbox-community/gruvbox'

Plug 'neovim/nvim-lspconfig'

Plug 'hrsh7th/cmp-nvim-lsp'
Plug 'hrsh7th/cmp-buffer'
Plug 'hrsh7th/nvim-cmp'

Plug 'nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter', {'do': ':TSUpdate'}  

Plug 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim'
Plug 'nvim-lua/popup.nvim'
Plug 'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim'

call plug#end()

lua << EOF

    require'lspconfig'.tsserver.setup{}
    require'lspconfig'.vuels.setup{}
    require'lspconfig'.vimls.setup{}
    require'lspconfig'.bashls.setup{}
    require'lspconfig'.csharp_ls.setup{}

EOF
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where is your config? What is the minimal config to reproduce?  Without that, all we can do is a wild guess.

Comment: @jdhao I've updated it

Comment: What is the output of command `which csharp-ls`?

Comment: @jdhao /home/user/.dotnet/tools/csharp-ls, I have also the dotnet/tools directory in my PATH variable

Comment: Your config seems fine to me. It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the files for nvim-lspconfig and I realized that csharp_ls wasn't even there. 
So I ran a `git pull` to get the latest files and it solved the problem.